# How to properly git clone with public key from gitlab?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have a gitlab projet on our local Gitlab instance configured and my account is set with a public key.

Strangely when I try to "git clone (...)" a project for which I have the correct permission from a client host, gitlab asks for a password even if it should pick my SSH key, no matter what is configured in my client SSH config file.

**git command**

```
git clone git@my_host.tld:username/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
git@my_host.tld's password:
```

**~/.ssh/config**

```
Host my_host.tld
        Hostname my_host.tld
        IdentityFile /root/.ssh/gitlab_key
        Preferredauthentications publickey
```

When I try to ssh using a regular command, it works:

**ssh command**

ssh -vT -i .ssh/my_host.tld

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: .ssh/gitlab_key
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to my_host.tld ([XX.XX.XX.XX]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: PTY allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: PTY allocation disabled.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = xx_X.UTF-8
Welcome to GitLab, @username!
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3600, received 3464 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6808.3, received 6551.1
debug1: Exit status 0
```

What have I missed? How to make git pick my SSH key instead of the password authentication method?

Comment: `PreferredAuthentications` with capital `A` in the middle.

Comment: Also, when your `Host` is the url already, you can omit `Hostname`.

Comment: When you ssh config is right, *you do not need to specify the key* (with `-i`). What is the result of `ssh -vT git@yourgitlab.tld`?

Comment: Also, what's the output of `ssh-add -L`?

Comment: Just noticed that your ~/.ssh/config references /root/.ssh/gitlab_key instead of something in your user's home. If you aren't running that command as the root user, then you won't have access to that key; if you are running that command as the root user, then you are playing with fire.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment to an answer:

You're specifying `/root/.ssh/gitlab_key` in the posted `~/.ssh/config`. User `~/.ssh` folders should only have mode 0700; this means that *only* that user can access the folder or any of its contents. I'm presuming here that you're running this command as yourself, and not as root, because you shouldn't use root for day-to-day work.

At minimum, you'll need to update your `~/.ssh/config` to reference your own key - the one that your `ssh -Tv` command worked with:

```
Host my_host.tld
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_host.tld
```

Comment: and to reinforce your previous point, *don't operate as root*